# not able to pass ofl parameter in request body in REST api of firebase dynamic link?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, rest

I am using firebase dynamic links where i used their REST api to create dynamic link. I am able to create the short link by using REST api and created link is working fine on android and ios app as well as on mobile browser. But i used same link on desktop browser it is not redirecting to play store page. Firebase provided "ofl" as a parameter to provide my intended functionality but there is no documentation to how i can pass that parameter in request body. Can anyone help me out ?

```
{
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "domainUriPrefix": "my_custome_domain_name",
    "link": "my_dynamic_link",
    "androidInfo": {
      "androidPackageName": "my_package_name",
      "androidFallbackLink": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my_package_name",
      "androidMinPackageVersionCode": "2"
    }
    "navigationInfo": {
      "enableForcedRedirect": true,
    }
  },
  "suffix": {
    "option":"UNGUESSABLE"
  }
}
```

Comment: they have added support to ofl as  "desktopInfo":{"desktopFallbackLink":"YOUR_DESKTOP_LINK"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, ofl is used to specify a different behavior on desktop, Like to display your webpage which gives brief info about your app or to display a link which can redirect to play store.... In your case you directly want to redirect to play store, so for that you can use **desktopFallbackLink** and provide your play store link of app

eg:

```
{
    "dynamicLinkInfo":{
        "domainUriPrefix":"my_custome_domain_name",
        "link":"my_dynamic_link",
        "androidInfo":{
            "androidPackageName":"my_package_name",
            "androidFallbackLink":"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my_package_name",
            "androidMinPackageVersionCode":"2"
        },
        "navigationInfo":{
            "enableForcedRedirect":true,
        }
    },
    "suffix":{
        "option":"UNGUESSABLE"
    },
    "desktopInfo":{
        "desktopFallbackLink":"https://www.other-example.com/"
    }
}
```